# Change *.txt to *.csv

Tags: terminal, bash

How can I rename all *.txt in a directory to *.csv files in the terminal (Mavericks). I tried following inside the directory:

```
mv *.txt *.csv
```

Comment: This can be done nicely in AppleScript. Then AppleScript can be called with the Terminal command `osascript`.

Answer (score 12):

You need to loop over all files

```
for f in *.txt; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.txt}.csv"
done
```

If you have files with names starting with a `.` as well you might need to run

```
for f in *.txt .*.txt; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "${f%.txt}.csv"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works well:

```
# change to the Zsh
zsh

# load the built-in zmv function
autoload -U zmv

# rename the files
zmv '(*).txt' '$1.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.txt |awk '{print "mv "$1" " substr($1,1,(index($1,".txt")))"csv"}' |sh
```

**Command explanation:**

`ls *.txt` lists files ending with txt

`| awk '{print "mv "$1" " substr($1,1,(index($1,".txt")))"csv"}` prints the command that allows to rename the previous files listed with txt to csv

`| sh` executes the previously printed command, thus effectively renaming the files

**Note:** if you want to list all files including hidden files (those starting with `.`) use `ls -a *.txt` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge number of files inside the directory, then even the ls*.txt command can fail, in that scenario, the below command can help:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' | sed 's/^\.\///g' | while read f1 ;do mv -v "$f1" "${f1%.*}.csv" ; done
```